# TSA server with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, apache, timestamp

From OpenSSL documentation of `openssl-ts` command:

> HTTP server support is provided in the form of a separate apache module

Does anybody know which module is the one? I haven't found any module to enable a TSA server.

Answer (score 1):

While [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/211762/6969) already stated that the apache module is dead, there is another open source software still developed and in use: [SignServer](https://www.signserver.org/) (developed by the same company as EJBCA).

Answer (score 0):

opentsa.org used to develop mod_tsa, in 2006. The site is dead as of 2013. I don't think anyone uses RFC 3161.

See https://web.archive.org/web/20120114151658/http://opentsa.org/